# NOOB capybara Rspec warning: regexp match /.../n against to UTF-8 string

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I have the following error when I use capybara with Rspec:

```
/Users/imac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@hbg_3.0.7/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/utils.rb:16: warning: regexp match /.../n against to UTF-8 string
.
```

After looking at the posted problem on github they suggest upgrading to rack 1.3.0.

I tried to do that but this is the problem:

If I add the rack gem to my gemfile and then do bundle install I get:

```
You have requested:
  rack = 1.3.0

The bundle currently has rack locked at 1.2.3.
Try running `bundle update rack`
```

And if I try to do bundle update rack I get:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In Gemfile:
    rspec-rails (= 2.6.0) depends on
      rack (~> 1.2.1)

    rack (1.3.0)
```

How can I update rack so that I can get rid of the error messages>

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I searched in google this such problem and found you question)) 
To solve - install `gem "escape_utils"` 
Then create file RAILS_ROOT/congif/initializers/escape_utils.rb with code:

```
module Rack
  module Utils
    def escape(s)
      EscapeUtils.escape_url(s)
    end
  end
end
```

and enjoy)

Thanks this guy to posted solution http://crimpycode.brennonbortz.com/?p=42

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. I did as instructed and it worked like a charm.